# Create a re-usable Java function

Tags: java, string, function, tapestry

I have a page in Java Tapestry that prints 3 blocks of text, let's call them BlockOfTextOne, BlockOfTextTwo, BlockOfTextThree. For each block of text, if the content is longer than 170 characters, I want to truncate the content and add a "read more" link.

I am using Java's handy `BreakIterator` class to return the first part of the block of text, cut at the sentence boundary closest to 170 characters, and then return the second part of the block of text following from that boundary.

I have this working for BlockOfTextOne. I would like advice on making my text truncating functions re-usable for each BlockOfTextN so that I don't need to repeat the code. I would also appreciate other suggestions for code improvements, what I have so far is more the result of experimentation than expertise.

Here's what I have so far:

In the TML file, I check if the string is longer than allowed. If yes, run truncate function and print readmore button. Else, just print the string:

```
<t:if test="isQuestionTooLong()">
  ${getBeginningOfBlockOfTextOne()}
  <button type="button" class="readmore">Read More</button>
  <div>${getTheRestOfBlockOfTextOne()}</div>
    <p:else>
     ${case.blockoftextwholestring} 
    </p:else>
</t:if>
```

In the .java file, I get the first bit of the block of text:

```
 public String getBeginningOfBlockOfTextOne() {   
    int summaryLength = blockoftextwholestring.length();
    BreakIterator bi = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance();
    bi.setText(blockoftextwholestring);
    int first_after = bi.following(MAX_LENGTH_TEXT_QUESTION);
    String firstBit = blockoftextwholestring.substring(0, first_after);
    return (firstBit);
}
```

Then I get the second bit of the block of text, duplicating much of the code, basically only changing the arguments passed to substring:

```
public String getTheRestOfBlockOfTextOne(){
    BreakIterator bi = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance();
    bi.setText(blockoftextwholestring);
    int first_after = bi.following(MAX_LENGTH_TEXT_QUESTION);
    String secondBit = blockoftextwholestring.substring(first_after, summaryLength);
    return (secondBit);
}
```

I know that I can break these down to re-usable components, but don't know the best way to do so. I also want to be able to re-use both of these for BlockOfTextTwo and BlockOfTextThree. Any suggestions?

Comment: so just pass the content String to the function, or am I misunderstanding you? Something like `getBeginningOfBlock(String wholestring) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Have one @Property for each string you want to display and initialize them in a @SetupRender method. The @SetupRender method can call a private helper method if you want.

Or, just have getters for each string you want to display on the page and delegate through to a private helper method.

BTW: `${getFoo()}` is better written as `${foo}`

Answer (score 0):

This so looks like something that should be implemented as a component. When you have redundant code it should be either a service (shared between pages and components) or a component (if it is UI oriented).

Components are so cheap and easy in Tapestry that you should always be thinking in terms of creating new ones. Just as you might refactor a large complex method into several small methods (even if the new methods are only invoked in one place), you should consider breaking a very large page into a number of components.